# Troubleshooting Airflow Task Failures: Slack Notification Timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, slack, slack-api

I'm running an Airflow DAG on Google Cloud Platform that should notify a Slack channel when a task fails. However, I'm encountering this issue:

When attempting to send a failure notification to Slack, the request times out, preventing the notification from being sent:

`{base_client.py:470} ERROR - Failed to send a request to Slack API server: <urlopen error timed out>`

This error persists even after retries. Is there a way to adjust the timeout settings, or could this indicate a network configuration issue preventing Airflow from communicating with Slack's API?

Any advice on troubleshooting these issue would be greatly appreciated.

I've been working on integrating a notification system into our Airflow workflows that alerts our team on Slack whenever a DAG fails. Specifically, I set up a task in a DAG to execute a SQL query using a Jinja template for the SQL file and then notify our Slack channel in case of failure. I expected Airflow to to successfully send an alert to our designated Slack channel.